# GoogleCloudSql Import not fail or succeed

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Created mysqldump file and uploaded to bucket: zip_zata_mysqldump and even though import does not show any failure, I don't see the databases created in the db.

How I can see what went wrong so I can fix?

Comment: Also I noticed that even if provide nonexisting file on the bucket, import does not complains???

Comment: If file is missing Developer Console operations page for SQL instance shows a specific error:
Failed to import to gs://bucketname/filename. File does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If import failed the operations tab shows a generic error "An unknown error occurred".

To receive a detailed error you can execute the import from command line with the following syntax:
mysql -h MYSQL_INSTANCE_IP -u USER -p DATABASE_NAME < SQL_FILE_TO_IMPORT

For your reference import and export features are documented at [1].

Regards,
Paolo

Link:
[1] - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/import-export

Comment: FYI, thru commandline, I managed to import the very same dump file that was failing to import thru UI

Answer (score 0):

For us adding `--hex-blob` in the `mysqldump` command allowed us to import. It failed `An unknown error occurred` without that flag.

Comment: regardless hex-blob used or not, in our case, the google ui didn't import though commandline worked